# C++: Stack is not unwound on exception thrown

Tags: c++, exception, object, shared

Hallo,

I have a quite strange problem in one of my C++ projects: 
I wrote a C++ Socket wrapper, that tries to connect to a given host and port (via IPv4/TCP) and throws a SocketException (derived from std::runtime_error), if an error occurs (e.g.  'Connection refused'). The exception is caught properly and an error message is written to console as expected, but apparently the destructor of my Socket class is not called (it should output a message to std::cerr, too, but the message only appears if connection works and Socket is destroyed later on if it goes out of stack, e.g. on end of the function that tries to utilize the socket). The destructor should close the encapsulated socket, but on exception thrown the socket remains open (you can see it with lsof as socket of unknown type), so no code in the destructor seems to be executed at all).
As I couldn't reproduce this problem with a simple testcase, my guess is that it somehow has to do with the quite complex structure of my project: I have a core application containing the code for the Socket class and providing a Singleton class which offers methods that implement the protocol used for communication and return the results of a request, each call to one of these methods generates its own instance of a Socket and provides it with the necessary information about host and port to use. To simplify socket generation and managment, a std::auto_ptr is used, which should delete the Socket if method has finished and stack is cleaned up, which works properly according to console output, but it should work the same way on an exception thrown, at least that is what was my opinion until now.
The core is able to load plugins in shared object format by dlopen and gets a pointer to the plugin's class instance via an extern C declared function in the shared object.
This instance now uses the Singleton provided by the core to communicate with the server and show retrieved data.

My question is: are there limitations to stack unwinding when using shared objects, or where should I look for the thing I missed out to make this work properly?

Comment: Code speaks louder than words.  Post the code and it will be easier to analyze.

Comment: Additional information: OS this is tried on is Linux, with GCC 4.3.2 (Debian Lenny) and GCC 4.4.x (Sabayon and Ubuntu Linux), glibc versions ranging from 2.7 to 2.11

Comment: Something you intended to happen didn't happen. The program is complex. What's wrong?

Comment: You would have to show the code of your socket wrapper (specifically the destructor), and the code where the unexpected behavior happens.

Comment: As I wrote above, I could not reproduce it with few simple lines of code, and the project itself is far too big to post it here. Is there any special part you'd like to see, like e.g. the implementation of SocketException class or the header of the Socket class?

Comment: If you have exception specifications (`throw(...)` in function declaration) then try to comment them all out and rebuild the project.

Comment: @Dialecticus, exception specifications don't really do anything, except call `std::terminate` if a unlisted exception is thrown

Comment: Are you compiling everything with exception support enabled? Check *especially* the units owning the `auto_ptr`s.

Comment: @Charles Salvia: Wrong. The compiler may assume that unlisted exceptions *don't* happen, and optimize the code basing on that assumption, without checking at runtime that it holds. Though in debug builds it could behave like you describe. Which brings us to the suggestion: OP, did you build your project with full debug enabled and check what happens then?

Comment: @slacker, are you sure about that?  The standard reads: "15.4.8: Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler encounters the outermost block of a function with an exception-specification, the function unexpected() is called if the exception-specification does not allow the exception."  If the compiler optimizes out exception throwing code based on an exception specification, how is it meeting this requirement of the standard?

Comment: @slacker You are wrong. The C++ standard says that the compiler has to **enforce** during runtime that unlisted exceptions don't happen. Maybe it sounds like a stupid idea to do it that way, but that's the way it is. Not every compiler conforms to the standard in this regard. Nowadays, the experts advice not to use exception specifications, and in the new C++ standard they will be deprecated.

Comment: @Charles Salvia, @Sjoerd: You guys are right. It is VC++ and compatibles (Borland!) that violate the standard by having `throw()` mean "this will never throw anything, so don't bother checking". I was so used to this behavior, I didn't even know that it's nonstandard. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your exception is thrown from the constructor, the destructor will not be called.

Comment: In that case, the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10) may help.

Comment: Note that members and base classes that have been fully constructed, will have their destructors called. As a result, the best solution to your problem probally is to split up the class in two parts: a part that manages the resource, and another one that does the required work using the resource. Google on RAII for more information.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: I'm very interested in this remaining bug in VC++ 10.0, would you be so kind as to enlighten me :) ?

Comment: @Mattieu: it would take a lot of googling, but if you're Really Interested the issue was most recently raised by James Kanze in the [comp.lang.c++] Usenet group (which is archived by Google Groups). The technical lead for Visual C++, and former chair of C++ committee, Herb Sutter, responded. It also flowed over to [comp.lang.c++.moderated]. You might use those names etc. for your google-foo. :-) Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, forget that one. Another look in the code showed that there was the possibility that an exception could have been thrown already in constructor so that the destructor would not have been called, as it's described in C++ standard. Not throwing in the constructor solved the problem. That's what programming in Java is doing to your C++ skills ^^
Excuse the noise, please.

Comment: Okay, so Armen Tsirunyan is right.  You should upvote/accept his answer.

Comment: You should also get a C++ book and forget Java, when you program C++. Also sounds like your class was doing too much. Either manage *one* resource, or *use* multiple resources. If acquiring your resource failed, you should throw. If that messes something else up, you've done it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming on linux, you might be triggering a problem where the exception thrown from a shared library is not caught properly (problem with exception type determining). This problem is explained [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/404) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43581), and I am sure you could google up more pages explaining the same problem.

If that is a problem, I am still looking for a solution :(